# Shell script which copy the file from another server to my box using SFTP without prompting for a password

Tags: shell, sftp

I want to write a shell script which copy the file from another server to my box using SFTP without prompting for a password as I have already made private keygen for password on server. Can you provide me the example script to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scp` which works on `ssh` protocol and read private keys as well:

`scp -r path/to/src/folder1 username@server:/path/to/dst/folder`

The `-r` switch is to copy recursively

If you need to specify port, use `-p`

`scp -r -P 2222 path/to/src/folder1 username@server:/path/to/dst/folder`

Comment: here the problem is I have to use SFTP file transfer/download as per my requirements.

Comment: scp is operating under the exact same ssh protocol, is there anything hindering you from using anything other than sftp?

Comment: yes comparing to the capabilities of both SFTP allows interrupted transfers and remote file removal also where as SSP only allows file transfers.